# Derivative of expected value

Tags: derivatives, random-variables, expected-value, dirac-delta, weak-derivatives

Let $X\geq 0$ be a real random variable, $Y(t), t\geq 0$ a stochastic process and $A\geq 0$. I want to determine the derivative of
$$F(z)=E[e^{X}(A-Y(X))\chi_{\{Y(X)\leq z\}}]$$
$X$ and $Y(X)$ have no density functions and no joint density.I thought about changing integral and derivative to get $$E[e^X(A-Y(X))\frac{d}{dz}\chi_{Y(X)\leq z}]$$. Now I want to calculate the weak derivative of this indicator function so I would get a delta function or a delta measure. Do you have any good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume $A$ is a constant. Let us write

$$ D = D(z) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \mathbb{E}\left[ e^X (A - Y(X)) \mathbf{1}_{\{ Y(X) \leq z \}} \right]. $$

Since it is possible that $D$ does not exist in ordinary sense, we regard $D$ as a weak derivative. To identify the nature of $D$, let $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$ be any test function and consider the pairing $\langle \varphi, D \rangle$. Then we get

\begin{align*}
\langle \varphi, D \rangle
&= - \left< \varphi'(z), \mathbb{E}\left[ e^X (A - Y(X)) \mathbf{1}_{\{ Y(X) \leq z \}} \right] \right> \\
&= - \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi'(z) \mathbb{E}\left[ e^X (A - Y(X)) \mathbf{1}_{\{ Y(X) \leq z \}} \right] \, \mathrm{d}z \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ e^X (A - Y(X)) \left( - \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi'(z) 
 \mathbf{1}_{\{ Y(X) \leq z \}} \, \mathrm{d}z \right) \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left[ e^X (A - Y(X)) \varphi(Y(X)) \right].
\end{align*}

In the third step, we applied Fubini–Tonelli theorem to interchange the order of integration. (Here, we are implicitly assuming that the condition for this theorem is indeed satisfied.)

The above computation confirms that $D$ is indeed the measure defined by

$$ B \quad \mapsto \quad \mathbb{E} \left[ e^X (A - Y(X)) \mathbf{1}_{\{Y(X) \in B\}} \right], $$

which we may write

$$ D = \mathbb{E} \left[ e^X (A - Y(X)) \delta_{Y(X)}(z) \right], $$

at least *formally* by exploiting the notation. This is essentially what we would expect when we mindlessly interchange the order between integration and differentiation and then invoke the formula $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \mathbf{1}_{\{a \leq z\}} = \delta_a(z)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to determine and explicit expression For $\frac{d}{dz}\left(E[e^{X}(A-Y(X))\chi_{\{Y(X)\leq z\}}]\right)$?

Comment: And what is $\delta_{Y(X)}(z)$?

Comment: @marc, $\delta_a(z)$ stands for the Dirac delta (i.e., unit point mass) concentrated at the point $a$. And without further information on $X$ and $Y(t)$'s, I see no way of further simplifying the expression.

Comment: I dont get why the above computation implies $ B \quad \mapsto \quad \mathbb{E} \left[ e^X (A - Y(X)) \mathbf{1}_{\{Y(X) \in B\}} \right]$ and $ D = \mathbb{E} \left[ e^X (A - Y(X)) \delta_{Y(X)}(z) \right].$ Can ylu explain me?

Comment: @marc, If $\mu$ is a signed Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$, then the values $\langle \mu,\varphi\rangle$ for $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$ completely determine $\mu$. Now, since the signed measure $\tilde{D}$ defined by $$\tilde{D}(B) = \left[ e^X (A - Y(X)) \mathbf{1}_{\{Y(X) \in B\}} \right]$$ satisfies $$\langle\varphi,\tilde{D}\rangle=\langle \varphi,D\rangle$$ for all test functions $\varphi$ (you can check this by yourself, for instance, by invoking monotone class theorem; this should be easy and routine!), we have $\tilde{D}=D$.

Comment: Also, using Dirac delta for representing the measure $$D(B)=\mathbb{E} \left[ e^X (A - Y(X)) \mathbf{1}_{\{Y(X) \in B\}} \right]$$ is more or less a formality. (Well, this can be justified as a genuine expectation, but this requires the notion of "expectation of distribution-valued random variable", and I am not sure if this is covered by your background.) Anyway, the idea is that for each fixed point $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the measure $B\mapsto \mathbf{1}_{\{x\in B\}}$ is precisely the Dirac delta $\delta_x(\cdot)$, hence, $D$ can also be interpreted as the expectation of Dirac deltas.